# Centering but lines aligned

Tags: math-mode, align

I want to add sub - scriptions centered below a formular, but I want everything to start with the same margin. Also I'd like to add a tab-kinda thing so the descriptions of each identity start below each other:

[image]

My MMW:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\vec{B} = \mu_0 \cdot (\vec{H} + \vec{M}) = \mu_r \cdot \mu_0 \cdot \vec{H}
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
\(\mu_r = 1 + \chi\): Permeabilitätszahl\\
\(\mu_0\): magnetische Felkonstante \\
\(\chi\): Suszeptibilität
\end{center}

\end {document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that nests an `aligned` environment in an `align` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for align and aligned environments and \text macro
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\vec{B} &= \mu_0 (\vec{H} + \vec{M}) = \mu_r \mu_0 \vec{H} \\[0.5ex]
&\quad\begin{aligned}
   &\textsf{$\mu_r = 1 + \chi$: Permeabilitätszahl}\\
   &\textsf{$\mu_0$: magnetische Felkonstante} \\
   &\textsf{$\chi$: Suszeptibilität}
\end{aligned} \notag
\end{align}

\end {document}
```

Comment: Great - thanks!